# Load Testing in jmeter

Tags: jmeter, load, performance-testing

Hi since I was not aware of load testing I got a doubt at the time of learning.
hope if it is a not valid also pls let me help.

In jmeter we can simply record and do load test right. if that is the  case if I load some unknown application with lots of load from my client side it might causes the server crashes right. then what should they do if server crashes of unknown person load test.

is there any specific things to do load test or simply we can do load test on any website .pls let me know this thing  even my query is not a valid one also...thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The majority of web applications are protected from [DoS attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack) therefore most likely you will not be able to "crash" the server, the traffic from your IP will simply get blocked and your IP will get banned.

Moreover, your action fall under [Computer Misuse Act](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1990/18/section/3) and you may be a subject to imprisonment up to 1 year and a fine up to 5000 pounds. The above law applies to the UK however I'm pretty much sure the equivalent exists in all the countries around the globe.

So don't load test the application without explicit permission of that application owner or you will run into a trouble.

Check out [Websites Forbidden to Test Using BlazeMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/206733009-Websites-Forbidden-to-Test-Using-BlazeMeter) for explicit list of web sites you must not test by any means. There are some sites you can use for practicing like http://newtours.demoaut.com/ or http://blazedemo.com/ however I would recommend using something you can deploy locally as this is the safest way to practice load testing, moreover you will be able to see server-side impact of your test